# Embed HTML5 / JS Web App with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed

I have been given a JSON url which returns some data. I need to create a javascript / html5 / css app that will grub this data and return it in a list.

Up to there I'm ok with doing this.

My issue is that I then need to be able to provide a `<script></script>` which the user can paste in any other website to display the web app.

The script or iframe need to be able to take parameters so it can filter the returned data.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is using global variables.

**Edit:** added a way to "embed" the generated content. I use jQuery in the example, but it can be easily done with any other DOM manipulation library or plain JS.

The final user add an HTML element with a specific `id` and a `<script>` tag containing the parameters. We use a `div` element in the example.

```
<div id="generated-list"></div>
<script>
    // the user defines parameters
    var configParameters = {param1: 'some value', param2: ['is', 'array']};
</script>
```

The final user should paste your code. I have no idea how is your code, so I made this up:

```
<script>
    // The user pastes your script here
    // which may be a function accepting the defined parameters
    function createList(configParameters) {
        // create the necessary elements and append them to the element
        // with the right id
        // We create an empty ul element in the example
        var newList = $('<ul></ul>');
        $('#generated-list').append(newList);
    }
</script>
```

Google analytics uses a similar approach

Comment: And how would I go about embedding it?

Comment: The details depends on the way your script generates the content, but it usually consists on creating new DOM elements. You can also create an iframe and write the list there

Comment: I added a very simple example of DOM creation using jQuery. It's hard to suggest a better solution without knowing more details about your code

Comment: So the first part : <div id="generated-list"></div>
<script>
    // the user defines parameters
    var configParameters = {param1: 'some value', param2: ['is', 'array']};
</script> is what the user would paste in he's website and part 2 would be my actual widget code?

Comment: Any chance you could do a jsfiddle of it? Can't get the basic's to work :o/